# upgraded node to v0.8 and started receiving an error for sys/util

Tags: node.js

I upgraded from node v0.6.12 to 0.80 and started receiving the error below - I have removed the sys module from the import but am still getting the error.  Any helpful hints would be helpful.  I am not suing stylus either.

```
path.exists is now called `fs.exists`.

sys.js:1

throw new Error(

Error: The "sys" module is now called "util".
at sys.js:1:69
at NativeModule.compile (node.js:602:5)
at Function.NativeModule.require (node.js:570:18)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:297:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/node/node_modules/stylus/lib/token.js:12:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: I upgraded to 0.8.1 and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to node v0.8.1. It will solve your problem